# cross ratio - what to do with the received factor?

Tags: math, image-processing, opencv

I have read a lot about projective geometry and cross ratio, but I don´t get a clue. Here is the problem:

I have four aligned points in a projective coordinate system: a, b, c, d
Something like this: a-------b--c------------d

The cross ratio should now be:

```
crossRatio = dst(ac)/dst(bc) / dst(ad)/dst(bd)
```

dst(ac) means the distance from point a to point c.
The result is e.g.: crossRatio=3,25.
I also have the length of dst(bc)=30cm in the real world. But since the points lie on a projective plane (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-ratio) I think I cannot determine the lengths of all the distances just like that.
So what does this cross ratio mean and how can I use it for measurements of lengths in projective geometry?I just get no picture how it all works together.

Edit: I rewrote the question (because of a downvote before. And please next time tell me WHAT is wrong and can be improved). Sorry for unclear description, I hope it is a bit better now.

Comment: Probably belongs on math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted the question in math.stackexchange in a bit different way and.... found out the answer my self after a decent amount of time. Look here, if interested.
[answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79510/cross-ratio-how-to-calculate-values-with-it/83064#83064)